# how to list spark-packages added to the spark context?

Tags: apache-spark, sparkr

Is it possible to list what spark packages have been added to the spark session?

The class `org.apache.spark.deploySparkSubmitArguments` has a variable for the packages:

```
var packages: String = null
```

Assuming this is a list of the spark packages, is this available via SparkContext or somewhere else?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I use the following method to retrieve that information:  `spark.sparkContext.listJars`

For example:
`$ spark-shell --packages elsevierlabs-os:spark-xml-utils:1.4.0`

```
scala> spark.sparkContext.listJars.foreach(println)
spark://192.168.0.255:51167/jars/elsevierlabs-os_spark-xml-utils-1.4.0.jar
spark://192.168.0.255:51167/jars/commons-io_commons-io-2.4.jar
spark://192.168.0.255:51167/jars/commons-logging_commons-logging-1.2.jar
spark://192.168.0.255:51167/jars/org.apache.commons_commons-lang3-3.4.jar
spark://192.168.0.255:51167/jars/net.sf.saxon_Saxon-HE-9.6.0-7.jar
```

In this case, I loaded the spark-xml-utils package, and the other jars were loaded as dependencies.

Comment: Upvoted, but not accepted yet.  The answer is for scala, but I was looking for something that would work with sparkr.

Comment: I've spent a couple hours combing through the SparkR documentation, code and the shell.  It does not appear that this functionality is directly exposed in the SparkR implementation.  I also did a few cursory attempts at retrieving information via sparkR.callJStatic without success.  Sorry!

Comment: That's as good as an answer - I.e there isn't a way to do this. Thanks for the help.